# Does the Fibonacci sequence modulo $m$ 'hit every possibility'?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the Fibonacci sequence and let $m$ be a fixed positive integer. Define $\{b^{(m)}_n\}$ by $b^{(m)}_n=a_n ~~\text{mod}~ m$. Does there exist $N$ such that, for $i\leq N$, $b_i^{(m)}$ takes on all possible values from $0$ to $m-1$? If yes, can the smallest such $N$ be estimated?

Brute-force calculating for some examples of $m$ (like up to $20$) seems to show a positive result, but honestly I have no idea how to even begin thinking about a formal proof (or disproof) for this. Even a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Working examples  would seem to be a natural place to start

Comment: Can you show your calculations for $m=8$?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A066853

Comment: Ok wow somehow I really messed up on this bad. Thank you for your answers everyone!